# HTML5 video player does not play mp4 h264 video in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, html5-video, mediaelement.js, owncloud

I have 2 videos (output from avconv):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8riTqvQMQTIOGxnUWFwVTRwSm8/view?usp=sharing (cutted version)

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2012-12-07 18:32:40
Duration: 00:03:07.38, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1369 kb/s
  Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1280x720 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1064 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2012-12-07 18:32:40
  Stream #0.1(und): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 301 kb/s
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2012-12-07 18:32:40
```

and

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8riTqvQMQTITF9sQXkxM1FQdzA/view?usp=sharing (cutted version)

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 2014-01-01 00:03:01
    encoder         : Lavf54.20.4
  Duration: 00:00:02.83, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 9815 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 9679 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-01-01 00:03:01
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-01-01 00:03:01
```

The size of 1st video - 32087109 bytes, 2nd - 11071658 bytes. They have the same codecs for video and audio, but behave different:

1. The 1st video is playing on the page using MediaElement.js (in html5 mode) in FF/Chrome.
2. The 2nd video is playing using MediaElement.js only in FF. In Chrome it tries to load it infinitely, but I can see that  element has got *MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED* error.
3. The 2nd video is playing in Chrome when you drag it from file system to browser.
4. The 2nd video does not start playing until full download (in Chrome it fails after full download, in FF you should wait until full download). The 1st one preloads some part and downloads new parts while playing.

I tried to insert  tag with second video directly to the page and no changes. The same *MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED* error.

The response headers from nginx are the same. But for second video the web page generates 2 requests: 1st with header `Range: 0-`, 2nd with header `Range: 28-`.

**Server:**

- Debian Jessie
- Nginx 1.6.2-5
- Owncloud 8.1.0 via https

**Client:**

- Ubuntu 14.04.2
- Google Chrome 43.0.2357.134 (64-bit)

**UPD.** Added cutted versions of videos (they are private, so only cutted).

Comment: Do you have any links to these videos?

Comment: @zer00ne added cutted versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug of owncloud. It serves all static files by itself and does not support partial content. You can read more about this here: [Odd video streaming behavior / serving "partial content"](https://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=29431).

[Serving Static Files for Better Performance](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.1/admin_manual/configuration_files/serving_static_files_configuration.html) article has helped me:  to solve the problem.